# Postman: Unable to authenticate using access token

Tags: access-token, postman

recently I decide use Postman but I can't create mocks because of this error 
"Unable to authenticate using access token." [image]

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which API you are trying to authenticate?

Comment: The URL is `https://postman-echo.com/get?test=123`. I am just following this documentation
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/mocking_with_examples

Comment: this is the message from postman support
`Hi Mher,

Thank you for getting in touch and I'm sorry that you've been unable to create a mock. It is an issue that we're aware of and our team is currently working on a fix. As soon as I have confirmation that the issue has been resolved, I'll let you know.

Best,
Rob`

so, don't spend your time on this issue, hope they will solve it soon.